# ElasticSearch Fielddata error on Rails 4 app using Chewy gem on one environment but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

We have a Rails 4 app running on two similar environments, `staging` and `production`.

Lately, this error started appearing on local development environments and the staging environment, but is not happening on production.

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {
  "error": {
    "root_cause":[{ "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. 
        Set fielddata=true on [updated_at] in order to load fielddata in memory 
        by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use 
        significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}],
      "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason":"all shards failed",
      "phase":"query",
      "grouped":true,
      "failed_shards":[{"shard":0,
      "index":"users",
      "node":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. 
          Set fielddata=true on [updated_at] in order to load fielddata in memory 
          by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use 
          significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}
    }]
  },
  "status":400
}
```

I know that the [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default) explains how to solve this error. However, I would like to know what could be triggering the error on those environments, given that the ES configuration and queries used are identical in staging and production.

Comment: Can you provide the mapping for both staging and production? It looks like `updated_at` may be mapped differently, either as a different type (the name _looks_ like it would be mapped as `date`, but the error indicates it's mapped as `text`) or _without_ `fielddata` set to `true`. How are the mapping created in both environments?

Comment: Managed to check the mapping directly on ES on both environments. The mapping on production was altered directly and not through the Chewy index file, and the updated_at field was set as `keyword` on prod. Thanks for your comment, @RussCam!

Comment: Can you please share how you solved this problem?

Comment: @UsamaMan our production environment had `updated_at` mapped as `text` -- So I changed it to `keyword`

Comment: @Ramses After that I would need to reindex the model?

Comment: @UsamaMan yes, that's correct